# dlopen fails in a library instantiating an object

Tags: libstdc++, dlopen, dlsym

We have a minimal working example of dlopen that works.

```
void* lib = dlopen("servlets.so", RTLD_NOW);
void* p = dlsym(lib, "getServlets");
```

However, if we add another function to the shared library (not even if it is called) then the library does not work (even though the code is never called)

```
uint32_t count = 0;
Servlet** servlets;
extern "C" {
  void generate() {
     servlets = new Servlet*[3];
     servlets[0] = new Servlet(...);
  }
  Servlet** getServlets() { return servlets; }
  uint32_t getServletNum() { return count; }
}
```

This must be because the code in the shared object is referencing some symbol that we don't have, but we do not know what.
The code compiles and links without a problem.

1. Is there any way to find out what the error is?  No error is reported, except that the library pointer returns NULL and the library does not load.
2. How do we link to a library so that dlopen works?

Comment: Try to explain _doesn't work_ What are the symptoms? Is there an error message? If `dlopen` returns NULL, call `dlerror` for error-message. (Note: if your shared library is in C++, then the main program must be C++ too, not C)

Comment: Try printing return value of `dlerror` or run program with `export LD_DEBUG=all`.

Comment: @Lorinczy was first, if you care to make it an answer i will mark it correct.

Comment: (Thanks, but it's not necessary, it's okay as it is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No error is reported, except that the library pointer returns NULL

A library pointer *can't* return anything. You probably mean `dlopen()` returns `NULL`.

If that's what you mean, *that is* the error being reported. If you want to know more about *why* the error was returned, use `dlerror()` to find out.